# Unicode characters in batch files

Tags: windows, batch-file, vbscript, cmd

I need to use a lot of characters from character map for this batch file.
Here is part of the batch file I am using:

```
"C:\v2.vbs" "C:\file.txt" 火 a
```

Is there a way to have cmd recognize the `火` or any other non-keyboard characters I have in the batch file? This command seems to only work if I don't use special characters.
What else could I use that will run a batch file and accomplish this?

Answer (score 4):

If this

```
"C:\v2.vbs" "C:\file.txt" <literal UTF-16 charcter> a
```

means "start v2.vbs with 3 arguments", then you could encode the second parameter like "&Habcd" (quotes needed) and use `sC = ChrW(WScript.Arguments(1))` in v2.vbs.